# SAT Math practice problem about seating arrangements that seems impossible! Can anybody offer any insight?

Tags: word-problem

A teacher is figuring out seating charts. If she assigns 2 people/table, she needs 4 extra tables. If she assigns 4 people/table, she has 4 empty tables. how many students are there in the class?

This was all the information I was given on the practice test and it was on the no-calculator version. Unfortunately, this was a secured exam so my instructor couldn't show me the answer key or help me in any way on it, only tell me if I got it right or wrong.

How would you guys do this?

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be the number of tables and $P$ be the number of students. The statement

> If she assigns 2 people/table, she needs 4 extra tables.

Translates to the relationship
$$ \frac{P}{2} = T + 4$$

The statement

> If she assigns 4 people/table, she has 4 empty tables.

Translates to
$$ \frac{P}{4} = T -4$$

This gives of a system of two equation and two variables. Can you solve the problem from here?

Comment: But what if 4 does not divide the number of students?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel The wording of the question suggests that the numbers of students is divisible by four. If this were not the case, there would be two possible answers.